# Verifying my HTML syntax

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I can't figure out what's going on, here is my HTML. The validator gives me errors, but I'm completely new to this so I have no clue how to fix it. Been trying for hours now. I don't get what most of the validators message implies, some say open elements or errors - but I can't find them.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages are self explanatory.  @Doelleri already spotted the `<class="contact">` wierd tag...

In addition, your `<a href="...">` tag is missing a `</a>`.

Ex:`<a href="email">email</a>`

Answer (score 2):

This all stems from your unclosed `<class="contact">` "element" which should be an attribute of another element, not its own element. Most likely what you want is:

```
<div class="contact">Prime Properties</div>
```

In the future please post your code as text, not as an image.